# Unable to install .ipa file using adHoc distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing Hybrid Apps for iOS  while cumming to the iOS app i amd registering UDID's of the devices and generating the **.IPA** file and distributing through Ad-Hoc process by using diawi.com & buildtry.com Previously it worked fine But from past  few days  these are not working with other networks  i mean the apps are able to get installed in the locally area network and suppose if they want to install in other area Like UAE,UK the are getting error like "**Unable to download app at this time ** OR After downloading the app to 50-80% it stucks" any other alternative other that testflight or hockeyapp or appbox

Comment: Can you give a try with Testfairy? Is your app related to MDM ?

Comment: I want a little open source or free ware one..

Answer (score 0):

It seems the download break.
However to get real reason, you need check ios log (From Xcode->Device and select iPhone to view Console log to see what happening when error message appear when install)

Comment: see this apps are working fine local networks but when it reaches to the other networks i mean otherplaces then only it is happening